# Add links into projection's nested object

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I use Spring Data REST's [projections](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts) feature in order to have some nested-typed objects inside JSON:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "name": "TEST",
   "user": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "user1"
   },
   _links: {
       self: {
           href: "http://localhost:8082/accounts/1{?projection}",
           templated: true
       },
       user: {
           href: "http://localhost:8082/accounts/1/users"
       },
    }
}
```

How can I generate links inside the nested object? I want the following JSON representation:

```
{
       "id": 1,
       "name": "TEST",
       "user": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "user1",
          _links: {
              self: {
                  href: "http://localhost:8082/users/1",
                  templated: true
              },
           }
       },
       _links: {
           self: {
               href: "http://localhost:8082/accounts/1{?projection}",
               templated: true
           },
           user: {
               href: "http://localhost:8082/accounts/1/users"
           },
        }
    }
```

P.S. I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28135166/how-to-add-links-to-spring-data-rest-projections), but don't have an idea how to use it in my case (if it's possible at all)

Comment: Have you tried a recent snapshot of Spring Data REST? We tweaked a bit of the default link rendering for projections recently?

Comment: @OliverGierke Can you please point me where should I look?

Answer (score 5):

I stumbled across this question, looking for a solution. After some fiddling with the [Spring Data REST docs section on Excerpts](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts.finding-projections) I have found out how to achieve this.

I assume `Account` is your root object and you want it to have a nested collection of `Users`, where each user in turn has `_links`.

**1:** Add an `Excerpt` for the Users object (this is a handy technique anyway to hide unimportant details on list collections)

```
@Projection(name = "userExcerpt", types = { User.class })
public interface UserExcerpt {
    String getName(); 
    String getEmail(); 
    ...
}
```

**2:** Associate the `Excerpt` with your `UserRepository`

```
@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection = UserExcerpt.class)
public abstract interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> ...
```

**3:** Add a `Projection` for `Account`:

```
@Projection(types = {Account.class})
public interface AccountUsersProjection {

    String getName();
    ...
    Set<UserExcerpt> getUsers();
}
```

The important bit here is that your Projection needs to reference `UserExcerpt` instead of `User`. This way the result returned from `GET /accounts/projection=accountUsersProjection`will look like this:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "accounts" : [ {
      "name" : "ProjA",
      "users" : [ {
        "name" : "Customer Admin",
        "email" : "customer@meshcloud.io",
        "_links" : {
          "self" : {
            "href" : "http://localhost:8080/users/2{?projection}",
            "templated" : true
          }, ...
        }
      } ], 
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/accounts/1"
        },
        ...
      }
    }  ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/accounts"
    },
    ...
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 50,
    "totalElements" : 2,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```