# Displaying Relation Links for @RestResource(exported = false)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I am using Spring Data Rest with Spring boot and I have somewhat odd situation.

- We need our clients to be able to post one resource with all it's relations in one JSON object, so we made the relations as `@RestResource( exported = false)`, this was the only solution we could find, the catch is we lose the links
- We are now trying to create a projection of this resource with all its relations displayed as links

What we tried so far is to create a projection with the non-relation attributes added with `getXXX()` and then use a `ResourceProcessor` to handle the links as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28135166/how-to-add-links-to-spring-data-rest-projections), but we cannot seem to get it to work

Q: is this the best way to approach this? How can we add links to projections like normal resources?

**UPDATE**
so here is my Projection class

```
@Projection(name = "fullSP", types = {SP.class})
public interface FullSP {}
```

and this is my Processor

```
@Component
public class FullSPResourceProcessor implements ResourceProcessor<Resource<FullSP>> {

private final EntityLinks entityLinks;

@Autowired
public FullSPResourceProcessor(EntityLinks entityLinks) {
    this.entityLinks = entityLinks;
}

@Override
public Resource<FullSP> process(Resource<FullSP> fullSPResource) {
    FullSP fullSP= fullSPResource.getId();
    fullSPResource.add(entityLinks.linkFor(Rate.class).withRel("rates"));
    return fullSPResource;
}
}
```

but this doesn't work, this just adds a link to /rates as a resource not as a sub resource

Comment: some code would help - especially projection and processor - maybe also the entity

Comment: @MathiasDpunkt updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EntityLinks has no knowledge about the subresource link you want to generate - so you get the default top-level link.

I assume you do not have a custom controller for this subresource?! If you don't spring-data-rest will not expose a subresource in this case - because the target of the relation is not `exported`.

In this case, you would need a custom controller to expose this subresource. If you go this route you should use `ControllerLinkBuilder` to build this link. If you want to stick with `EntityLinks` you could do the following (for the link you would need the id - to get it it needs to be available on the projection):

```
fullSPResource.add(entityLinks.linkForSingleResource(SP.class, fullSPResource.getContent().getId()).slash("rates").withRel("rates"));
```

Comment: I will give it a shot, I will try the controller solution first